# Diferença de horas - SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Estou estudando SQL no SQLite, porém me deparei com uma "barreira": estou tentando calcular a diferença de tempo, porém ou aparecem números flutuantes ou números inteiros que não correspondem ao que preciso.

```
iDT_INICIAL = 2023-11-26 06:00:00
iDT_FINAL = 2023-11-26 06:00:58
iRESULT = 00:00:58
```

É possível trazer neste mesmo formato com SQLite?

Já tentei DATETIME, DATEADD (com valor negativo) e mesmo assim não funciona. Onde estou errando?

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html#:~:text=The%20timediff()%20function%20is,B)%20%2D%20unixepoch(A)%3B